Running Keycloak in Docker - Production
Have a few questions regarding my setup for production Keycloak environment running in Docker. Have it "working" but not acceptable for production.
NOTE: have removed https from most configs due to this post (first in stack overflow) being detected as spam...
Below are the current setup and configs for the Keycloak docker server setup.
Nginx config
After running Lets Encrypt
server {
    server_name  keycloak.tld.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/auth.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/auth.error.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_pass //localhost:8443;
  }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.tld.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.tld.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = keycloak.tld.com) {
        return 301 //$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name  keycloak.tld.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

I run Lets Encrypt and get the certs before the building of the images so I can use them in the image to allow immediate accessibility via https...
Docker setup
I used Dockerfile (according to Keycloak guide here Running Keycloak in a container) and made some modifications regarding ssl certs and volume...
# Currently 25.0.1 is the latest, just in case of breaking changes in future :latest, force base image updates to be specified
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.1 as builder

# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true

# Database vendor Postgres
ENV KC_DB=postgres

# Copy the LetsEncrypt created SSL certs to container with correct permissions
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
COPY --chown=1000:0 certs/fullchain.pem /opt/keycloak/fullchain.pem
COPY --chown=1000:0 certs/privkey.pem /opt/keycloak/privkey.pem

RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.1
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# Pointing to external postgres (container) shared database on pgres_default network
ENV KC_FEATURES=hostname:v2
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb/keycloak 
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=cloak
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=some_super_strong_password
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=keycloak.tld.com
ENV KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/opt/keycloak/fullchain.pem
ENV KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/opt/keycloak/privkey.pem
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh"]

# Not sure on below (attempt to simplify LetsEncrypt certs auto update by potentially copying pems to here... or just run a script to copy into container direct every few weeks...)
VOLUME keycloak-data:/opt/keycloak/

As per Keycloak site I then run below to create the 'optimized' image:
docker build . -t mysite-keycloak

I can then start the service with options:
docker run --name mysite-keycloak --net pgres_default -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 -p 9000:9000 -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=keyadmin -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=super_strong_password -v keycloak-data mysite-keycloak start --optimized --verbose

I want to run from a docker-compose.yml file instead to keep everything tidy and easy to follow/backup/reuse later...
networks:
  pgres_default:
    external: true
services:
  keycloak:
      image: mysite-keycloak
      container_name: mysite-keycloak
      command: start
      restart: always
      env_file: "auth.env"
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
        - 8443:8443
        - 9000:9000
      volumes:
        - keycloak-data:/opt/keycloak
volumes:
  keycloak-data:

The auth.env file
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER: keyadmin
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: super_strong_password
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL="//keycloak.tld.com"
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true

THE ISSUES
By running docker build . -t mysite-keycloak the image is created fine.
I am then able to start the container with the docker run ... command above, which starts fine and keycloak.tld.com is reachable.
However, when going to keycloak.tld.com the browser appends the port (:8443) to the domain... All pages of admin console work fine, but on my other (older) Keycloak server the port is hidden...
I do not want to use docker run and would instead prefer to use the docker-compose.yml file. The above yaml works, however, it is unable to connect to the database and getting Datasource '<default>': Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb/keycloak error... Guessing maybe the external network is not setup correct in the yaml file?
The SSL certs, is there a better way than copying the renewed certs into the container (hoping to just mount the volume that Lets Encrypt stores the files into so that the container automatically sees any updates...)?
Should I map the ports differently (eg; 48443:8443 etc...) for more security and if so, how would this affect the nginx .conf file setup? Any other stuff ups? This is for production environment so needs to be production ready...
Thanks in advance for all helpful responses!
